# Get all data from the table using form (Angular - ngx-datatable)

Tags: angular, forms, pagination, ngx-datatable

I am using Angular with the ngx-datatable plugin to display a data series. I have wrapped this table in a form and have added several controls on it (input hidden with id row, checkbox and select) to modify said data later in the component according to the selected values.

My intention is to update them in a massive way, that is, to make the pertinent changes in each of the rows of the table and send the (hidden id + checkbox value + select value) of each of them to the component. What is the problem ? By submitting the data (Press submit button of the form), I only get the records of the current page that is being displayed from the table, instead of getting all the records of all the pages.

I am still a novice in this framework and the truth is that it is giving me a lot of headaches. I put my current code below, I also tried to do it through @Viewchildren with a reference to the list of hidden inputs (#idsUsers), checkbox (#addToGroup) and selects (#roleGroup) but I always get those of the page that is being displayed from the table, instead of being able to get all of them . Thank you very much in advance!

HTML:

```
<!--Form definition-->
<form #colaboratos="ngForm" id="formColaborators" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(colaboratos.value)" novalidate>

   <!-- Data table -->
  <ngx-datatable
    #userList
    class="material ml-0 mr-0"
    [rows]="itemsUsers"
    [columnMode]="'force'"
    [headerHeight]="50"
    [footerHeight]="50"
    [scrollbarH]="true"
    [limit]="6"
    [rowHeight]="50"
    (activate)="onActivate($event)">
    <ngx-datatable-column prop="idUser" name="ID" [flexGrow]="1">
      <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        {{ row?.id }}
        <!--We store user id for data update-->
        <mat-form-field [hidden]="true">
          <input 
            #idsUsers
            matInput
            value="row.id"
            id="idUser_{{row.id}}"
            class="idUser"
            name="idUser_{{row.id}}"
            type="text"
            [(ngModel)]="row.id">
        </mat-form-field>
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>
    <ngx-datatable-column prop="userFirstName" name="FIRST NAME" [sortable]="true" [flexGrow]="1">
      <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        {{ row?.firstName }}
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>
    <ngx-datatable-column prop="userSurname" name="SURNAME" [sortable]="true" [flexGrow]="1">
      <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        {{ row?.lastName }}
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>
    <ngx-datatable-column prop="userEmail" name="EMAIL" [sortable]="true" [flexGrow]="1">
      <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        {{ row?.email }}
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>
    <ngx-datatable-column prop="userAddtoGroup" name="ADD TO GROUP" [flexGrow]="1">
      <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        <mat-checkbox 
          #addToGroup
          [ngModel]="belongstoresearchgroup(row.id)"
          name="addToGroup_{{row.id}}"
          id="addToGroup_{{row.id}}"
          class="addToGroup"
          >
        </mat-checkbox>
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>
    <ngx-datatable-column prop="userRole" name="ROLE" [flexGrow]="1">
      <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        <mat-select
        #roleGroup
        matInput
        name="roleGroup_{{row.id}}"
        [ngModel]="roleAssign(row.id)"
        id="roleGroup_{{row.id}}"
        class="roleGroup">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let role of rolesGroup" [value]="role.id">
            {{role.scopeTr}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>
  </ngx-datatable>
<!-- /End of form-->
</form>
```

COMPONENT:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild, ViewChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';
import { ColaboratorsService } from '../colaborators.service';
import { MatDialog, MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
import { AppConfirmService } from '../../../../shared/services/app-confirm/app-confirm.service';
import { AppLoaderService } from '../../../../shared/services/app-loader/app-loader.service';
import { Subscription} from 'rxjs';
import { egretAnimations } from "../../../../shared/animations/egret-animations";
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { ApiService } from '../../../../shared/services/api.service';
import { AuthenticationService } from './../../../../shared/services/authentication.service';

import { User } from './../../../../shared/models/user.model';
import { Role } from './../../../../shared/models/role.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-colaborators-table',
  templateUrl: './colaborators-table.component.html',
  animations: egretAnimations
})
export class ColaboratorsTableComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChildren('idsUsers') listidsUsers:QueryList<any>;
  @ViewChildren('addToGroup') listCheckboxAddToGroup:QueryList<any>;
  @ViewChildren('roleGroup') listSelectRoleGroup:QueryList<any>;

  public itemsUsers: any = [];
  public rolesGroup: Role[] = [];

  public itemUser: User;

  currentUser: User;

  loading = false;
  submitted = false;

  constructor(
    private actRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private dialog: MatDialog,
    private snack: MatSnackBar,
    private colaboratorsService: ColaboratorsService,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private confirmService: AppConfirmService,
    private loader: AppLoaderService,
    private router: Router,
    private apiService: ApiService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if(!window.localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
      this.router.navigate(['/sessions/login']);
      return;
    }

    this.loadRolesGroupInvestigation();

    this.actRoute.data.subscribe(() => {
      this.itemsUsers = this.actRoute.snapshot.data.users;
      this.temp = [...this.actRoute.snapshot.data.users];
    });
  }


  belongstoresearchgroup(id): boolean {
    let belongsgroup = false;
    let item = this.itemsUsers.find(x => x.id === id);

    if(Object.keys(item.investigationGroupUser).length){
      belongsgroup = true;

    }
    return belongsgroup;
  }


  roleAssign(id): string {
    let idRoleAsignado = '';
    let item = this.itemsUsers.find(x => x.id === id);

    if(Object.keys(item.investigationGroupUser).length){
      idRoleAsignado = item.investigationGroupUser.roleId;
    }
    return idRoleAsignado;
  }


  onActivate(event) {
    if(event.type == 'click') {
        console.log(event.row);
    }
  }

  onSubmit(val) {
    alert("form send");
    //I only get records from the page of the table being displayed when you click save form

    //first method (data send from form)
    console.log(val);

    //second method (data from viewchildren)
    console.log(this.idsUsers.toArray());
    console.log(this.addToGroup.toArray());
    console.log(this.roleGroup.toArray());
  }


  loadRolesGroupInvestigation() {
    return this.apiService.GetRoles().subscribe(data => {
      this.rolesGroup = data['list'];
      data['list'].forEach(role=>{
        if(role.statusTr == "Active" && !role.deletedById){
          this.rolesGroup.push(role);
        }
      });
    })
  }
}
```